# Concatenate Negative Number and String in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I'm having a trouble in concatenating the Negative numbers and Strings.  I've successfully display the negative numbers with parenthesis (ex. (3)) but when I add the string to it the format of number becomes -3 again. This is my expression:

```
=Cint(Fields!UNT_TAKEN.Value) & " UNITS"
```

It returns me with this value `-3 UNITS`

But I want to return `(3) UNITS`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If UNIT_TAKEN is already a number then you can just set the format property of the cell/textbox to

```
0 Units;(0) Units
```

If UNIT_TAKEN is a string then set the value expression of the cell/textbox to

```
=FORMAT(CINT(Fields!UNIT_TAKEN.Value),"0 Units;(0) Units")
```

Below I created a dataset with both a numeric and string version of seven numbers. The table below shows the actual values and the formatted values as above.

[image]